# Want to rewrite path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have file organised like this -

- www.mysite.com/cars/ford/ford.php
- www.mysite.com/cars/bmw/bmw.php

I want users to be able to visit these pages without specifying the xyz.php file at the end.

- www.mysite.com/cars/ford
- www.mysite.com/cars/bmw

What do I used for a rewrite rule that well let users visit pages using that format?

Comment: That's a common scenario. Have you looked at the [mod-rewrite tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) yet? Where did you stumble on writing the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you change all your links to the `www.mysite.com/cars/ford` form, you need to put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?cars/([^/])/?$ /cars/$1/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is more complete and robust than my answer. @Jim_CS use this.

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule /cars/(.*)$ /cars/$1/$1.php [L]
```